# Validator::replacer() doesn't convert :attribute to uppercase in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to capitalize the first character in :attribute but my `Validator::replacer()` doesn't let me do that.

Here's what I have:

```
Validator::replacer('name', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    return str_replace(':attribute', ucfirst($attribute), $message);
});
```

and in my lang/en/validation.php file

```
"name": ':attribute should be more than 2 characters'
```

I'm expecting the error message to be "Name should be more than 2 characters" but I see "name should be more than 2 characters"

Comment: The function is `ucfirst`, not `ucfist` (you're missing the `r`).

Comment: Sorry for that typo here. But I do have `ucfirst()` in my code

Comment: What version of Laravel is this?

Comment: `Laravel 5.6.40`

Comment: And where are you calling `Validator::replacer`?

Comment: I added it in my `AppServiceProvider.php` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233243/discussion-between-stephen-lewis-and-bharath).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use `:Attribute` in your translation string, rather than `:attribute`.

Laravel will then [automatically capitalise the first letter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings).

Comment: yes, I just figured it though I'm not sure how good is this solution because `str_replace` should work fine without `:Attribute`

Comment: Mine on the other hand is already in lowercase `:attribute`, however, still gives me an error in capitalize format. `The Name field is required.`

Comment: Somebody asked me why I didn't accept this answer. Actually I was the one who found this solution but when I told the person who wrote this answer about this solution in the chat, he added this before me. So I can't accept this answer as it is mine.

Comment: @BTK Not quite [how it went down](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233243/discussion-between-stephen-lewis-and-bharath), but if you'd prefer to add your own answer, I'll happily remove mine.

Comment: @StephenLewis Nah, that's not right. I told you about this solution before you did. [Please check Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52331557#52331557). But you can keep your answer, I don't mind that.